# Custom API With Array of Some Specific Field with ACF Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, rest, endpoint

I am trying to create a custom API with ACF but I am stuck because I need an array of team players but I am new in the coding field so I don't know how to do this
I am using ACF free version
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I0ih.jpg

my custom API code is for custom api

```
function wl_cricket_team() {
    $args = [
        'numberposts' => 99999,
        'post_type' => 'cricket_team'
    ];

    $posts = get_posts($args);



    $data = [];
    $i = 0;

    foreach($posts as $post) {
        $data[$i]['id'] = $post->ID;
        $data[$i]['title'] = $post->post_title;
        $data[$i]['team'] = get_field('team', $post->ID);
        $data[$i]['Players'] = get_field('players', $post->ID,);


        $i++;
    }

    return array(
           'cat' => $data,
);
}
```

how to convert ACF custom field (players) object into an array (with index)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ToBT.png)

[what I received v/s what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ToBT.png)
[enter image description here][2]

Comment: what type of ACF filed is `players`?

Comment: 1. Text. Basic,  2. image,  3. nested object which contains 8 number field and 1 double number(Exp = 0.74)